# Show that in every euclidean vector space E...

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that in every euclidean vector space E that:

$\|x + y\|$ $^2 + \|x - y\|^2 = 2 \|x\|^2 + 2\|y\|^2$

for every $ x,y \in E$

Interpret the formula in a geometric manner.

Not really sure what to do here, am I just supposed to expand the formula or something?

Comment: Hint. In Euclidean geometry this is called the "parallelogram law". Draw a parallelogram with adjacent edges $x$ and $y$ and see what it says.

Comment: Use $\|x\|^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$ and write everything out. Geometrically, it is called the *parallelogram law* for a reason.

Comment: Or use that $\|x\|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$ is defined by an inner product (symmetric positive definite bilinear form)

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
\begin{align}
\lVert x+y \rVert^2 &= \langle x+y , x+y \rangle \\
 &= \langle x , x+y \rangle + \langle y , x+y \rangle \\
 &= \langle x , x \rangle + \langle x , y \rangle + \langle y , x \rangle + \langle y , y \rangle \\
 &= \lVert x \rVert^2 + \langle x , y \rangle + \langle y , x \rangle + \lVert y \rVert^2
\end{align}
Similarly,
$$ \lVert x-y \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 - \langle x , y \rangle - \langle y , x \rangle + \lVert y \rVert^2. $$
Add to get the result.

As mentioned in the comments, the geometric interpretation of this comes from the Euclidean geometry result that the sum of the squares of the diagonals of a parallelogram is equal to the sum of the squares of the sides. ($x+y$ is one diagonal of the parallelogram with nonparallel sides formed by $x$ and $y$, $x-y$ the other)